# How to pass variable from jade-loader to a jade template file?

Tags: pug, webpack

I want to pass my data-object to jade files, but but it is impossible
My `jade-loader`:

```
{
   test: /\.jade$/,
   loader: "jade",
   query: {
      pretty: true,
      locals: {
          name: "Georg"
    }
}
```

}

`plugins`:

```
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
       filename: "index.html",
       template: "./src/jade/index.jade"
})]
```

`index.jade`:

```
span=locals.name
```

I run webpack and I get this `index.html`:

```
<span></span>
```

My variable `name` don't pass. Why? How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the custom properties to `HtmlWebpackPlugin` options and use them in your pug templates (see [htmlWebpackPlugin.options](https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin#writing-your-own-templates) in documentation). It works with the latest versions of the `HtmlWebpackPlugin`, `pug-loader` and webpack 2. Can't confirm that it works with the previous versions, but I believe it does.

`pug` rule:

```
{
  test: /\.pug$/,
  loader: 'pug-loader',
  options: {
    // Use `self` namespace to hold the locals
    // Not really necessary
    self: true,
  },
}
```

`HtmlWebpackPlugin` options:

```
{
  filename: 'index.html',
  template: 'src/html/index.pug',

  // Your custom variables:
  name: 'Georg',
}
```

Using it in `index.pug` template:

```
span= self.htmlWebpackPlugin.options.name
```

Note that you can set the `self` option to `false` and omit it in your pug templates using variables directly. For more details see the [Pug reference](https://pugjs.org/api/reference.html).

Answer (score 1):

you should use [pug-html-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pug-html-loader)

then in `webpack.config.js`

```
  ...
  {
    test:/\.pug$/,
    exclude: ['/node_modules/'],
    loader: 'pug-html-loader',
    query: {
      data: {name:'test'},
      pretty: true
    }
  },
  ...
```

then in your pug(jade) files, use this data

```
 h3.title= data.name
```