# Make variable accessible in all pug files

Tags: webpack, pug

Using [pug-loader](https://github.com/pugjs/pug-loader) how can I make some vairable accessible to all pug/jade files. For example in express app I could do:

`app.locals.assetPath = path.resolve('public/assets');`

and the variable `assetPath` would be available in all jade files. But with webpack I am not able to do the same.

In my `webpack.config.js` I tried following but could not get work:

```
{
  test: /.pug$/,
  loader: 'pug',
  query: {
    root: path.join(__dirname, 'src/app'),

    /*globals: {assetPath: '/hard/coded/value'}*/ //WILL NOT WORK

    /*locals: {assetPath: '/hard/coded/value'}*/ //WILL NOT WORK

    /*locals: {assetPath: '/hard/coded/value'}, globals: ['assetPath']*/ //WILL NOT WORK
  }
```

Comment: If I'm reading the source right, you need to extend pug-loader to support what you want. You could open an issue at the repo and see what they say.

Comment: Opened a github issue [here](https://github.com/pugjs/pug-loader/issues/57)

Answer (score 4):

From my experience, you have two options:

- use [pug-html-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pug-html-loader) instead;
- if you are using `HtmlWebpackPlugin` plugin, add custom properties to its config. They will be accessible through all pug templates.

Please, take a look at the detailed **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755652/how-to-pass-variable-from-jade-loader-to-a-jade-template-file/41375787#41375787)** concerning the second and the first options.

Here is also the configuration example for the second option:

`pug` rule:

```
{
  test: /\.pug$/,
  loader: 'pug-loader',
  options: {
    // Use `self` namespace to hold the locals
    // Not really necessary
    self: true,
  },
}
```

`HtmlWebpackPlugin` options:

```
{
  filename: 'index.html',
  template: 'src/html/index.pug',
  // Your custom variables:
  production: (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production')
}
```

`index.pug` template:

```
- const production = self.htmlWebpackPlugin.options.production

if production
  link( rel="stylesheet", type="text/css", href="style.css" )
```