# Pass data to pug using pug-html-loader (cannot read property of undefined)

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, pug, webpack-html-loader

According to the readme of [pug-html-loader](https://github.com/willyelm/pug-html-loader/blob/master/README.md), the loader accepts a `data` object which is being passed as part of the `options` to the template. While not available on the `options` within the [pug API reference](https://pugjs.org/api/reference.html), a grunt plugin I've found ([grunt-contrib-pug](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-pug)) uses the API the same way.

I've specified the following options for the loader:

```
  loader: 'pug-html-loader',
  options: {
    pretty: true,
    exports: false,
    debug: !env.production,
    compileDebug: !env.production,
    cache: config.build.useCaching,
    doctype: 'html',
    data: {
      title:    config.metadata.title,
      baseUrl:  config.build.baseUrl,
      server:   env.server,
      metadata: config.metadata
    }
  }
```

Which I'd like to access the following way, according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755652/how-to-pass-variable-from-jade-loader-to-a-jade-template-file):

```
title= data.title
```

However, I always run into the following error when compiling:

```
ERROR in   Error: Child compilation failed:
  Module build failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined
```

For debugging purposes, I've included the following line in the template:

```
-
  console.log(' DATA! ' + data);
```

Which results in:

```
DATA! undefined
```

I've also ensured that the data is correctly being passed to pug by declaring some gibberish instead of an object (e.g. a string, plain json, a number..), then the pug compiler complains that the data is not in valid format etc.

Anyone facing the same issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should reference data directy (i.e. without prefixing the fields with `data`)

So you should change your code like so:

```
{
  loader: 'pug-html-loader',
  options: {
    data: {
      title: 'Hello World'
    }
  }
}
```

And then reference it from your PUG template **Updated**

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
```

Comment: Don't you mean `title=title` or `data: { hello: 'Hello World' }`