# JADE how to use js variable in external file

Tags: javascript, html, pug

I use templating syntax JADE
http://jade-lang.com/

I have an external js (text.js) file with some text variables

```
module.exports = {
  TITLE: 'my title',
}
```

In my JADE file i want to use my variable, how to do that, i have try this but it's doesn't work

```
script(src="./text.js")

  p My variable
  p #{TITLE}
```

How to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to specify in your question how are you using jade.

Comment: You can use `https://www.npmjs.com/package/pug-html-loader` instead of `jade-loader`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37755652/how-to-pass-variable-from-jade-loader-to-a-jade-template-file

Comment: You need to pass the object that you want to access in your jade file when rendering i.e. `res.render('myjadefile', {TITLE: 'my title'});`